# Black Bar Appearing Above Keyboard - Xcode Error

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, uikeyboard

A black bar has been appearing over different types of text fields when they are tapped on. i don't know why but it happened when I upgraded to xcode 8. Here is a picture:

[image]

This happens when it goes from a normal text field to a different type of keyboard like a number pad or password type keyboard. I think a solution might be disabling the word suggestion bar but I am not to sure.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
textField.inputAccessoryView = nil
```

Comment: try to add self.view.layoutIfNeeded() everytime the keyboard will show.

Comment: Make a notification or set the delegate of the textField

Comment: Is that in the simulator? Have you tried on an actual device?

Comment: I have tried an actual device and the problem still remains